# What is the difference between display:inline and display:block?

Tags: css

What is the basic difference between the following CSS:

```
display:inline
```

and this:

```
display:block
```

Using these separately on an element, I get the same result.

Comment: See [Is there any guide on "When to use display:block when :inline and when :inline-block" and why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043021/is-there-any-guide-on-when-to-use-displayblock-when-inline-and-when-inline-bl)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**display: block** means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another element, for instance).

**display: inline** means that the element is displayed inline, inside the current block on the same line. Only when it's between two blocks does the element form an 'anonymous block', that however has the smallest possible width.

Read more about display options : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Are there any elements that are inline by default? Span?

Comment: <span> <a> and <img>

Answer (score 89):

**Block**

Takes up the full width available, with a new line before and after (display:block;)

**Inline**

Takes up only as much width as it needs, and does not force new lines (display:inline;)

Answer (score 46):

`display: block` - a line break before and after the element

`display: inline` - no line break before or after the element

Answer (score 38):

Here is a comparison table:[image]

You can view [examples here.](https://gist.github.com/Asheq/1ef5ec77b8e89c2c9da89d2b7a1cf8cb)

Answer (score 14):

`display: block;` creates a **block-level** element, whereas `display: inline;` creates an **inline-level** element. It's a bit difficult to explain the difference if you're not familiar with the css box model, but suffice to say that block level elements break up the *flow* of a document, whereas inline elements do not.

Some examples of block level elements include: `div`, `h1`, `p`, and `hr` HTML tags.

Some examples of inline level elements include: `a`, `span`, `strong`, `em`, `b`, and `i` HTML tags.

Personally, I like to think of inline elements as *typographical* elements. This isn't entirely or technically correct, but for the most part inline elements do behave a lot like text.

You can read a more through article on the topic [here](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/). Seeing as several other people in this thread have quoted it, it may be worth a read.

Answer (score 8):

**Display : block** will take the whole line i.e without line break

**Display :inline** will take only exact space that it requires.

```
 #block
  {
   display : block;
   background-color:red;
   border:1px solid;
  }

 #inline
 {
  display : inline;
  background-color:red;
  border:1px solid;
 }
```

You can refer example in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RJXZM/1/.

Comment: superb... this what i'm looking

Answer (score 8):

**block** elements expand to fill their parent.

**inline** elements contract to be just big enough to hold their children.

Answer (score 6):

**display:block**

takes the entire row(100%)of the screen ,it is always 100%of the screen size

[display block example](http://prntscr.com/94fqor)

**display:inline-block** takes up as much width as necessary ,it can be 1%-to 100% of the screen size

[display inline-block example](http://prntscr.com/94frao)

that's why we have **div and span**

Div default styling is display block :it takes the entire width of the screen

span default styling is display:inline block :span does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary

Comment: that's why we have div and span - this one is Awesome bro :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a background-color to the element and you will nicely see the difference of inline vs. block, as explained by the other posters.

Answer (score 1):

Display:block
It very much behaves the same way as 'p' tags and it takes up the entire row and there can't be any element next to it until it's floated.
 Display:inline 
It's just uses as much space as required and allows other elements to be aligned alongside itself.

Use these properties in case of forms and you will get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

a block or inline-block can have a width (e.g. width: 400px) while inline element is not affected by width. inline element can span to the next line of text (example http://codepen.io/huijing/pen/PNMxXL resize your browser window to see that) while block element can't.

```
 .inline {
      background: lemonchiffon;
      div {
        display: inline;
        border: 1px dashed darkgreen;
      }
```

Comment: This reads like is is supposed to be a reply to to one of the other eight answers on this question. I can't tell which one though.

Comment: most of them. just adding to the info.

Answer (score 0):

**Block Elements**: Elements liked div, p, headings are block level. They start from new line and occupy full width of parent element. 
**Inline Elements**: Elements liked b, i, span, img  are inline level. They never start from new line and occupy width of content.