# I am trying to give my drop down background color, but its not implementing on it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

index.htm:
[image: index.html]

styles.css:
[image: styles.css]

```css
.menubar .sub_menu {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<li class="fa fa-code">
  <a href="#skills"> Skills</a>

  <ul class="sub_menu">
    <li><a href="">Front-End</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Back-End</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Full-Stack</a></li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background-color for ul/div element not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152285/background-color-for-ul-div-element-not-rendered)

Answer (score 2):

your CSS suggests that the class `sub_menu` should be under the class `menubar`. You can try removing that requirement

```
.sub_menu {
        background-color: aqua; 
}
```

Comment: But I have tried removing that. But it still doesn't work out. I've done like you have suggested. But it's the same result No.

Comment: But I have tried removing that. But it still doesn't work out. I've done like you have suggested. But it's the same result No.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```css
.sub_menu {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: Already tried, but doesn't work out!

Comment: if you share code then it will help us to understand your problem / not image.