# a class, issue with width. height and margin

Tags: html, css, class

I am trying to create buttons without using CSS3 "button". Float, height and width do not work.

```
a.reply {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

a:hover.reply {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML and maybe a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use inline-block

```
a.reply {
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px;
background-color: #555;
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`width`, `height`, `margin` can only work on a element that has dimension, aka block level element.

So you need to add the `display: block`, or `display: inline-block` properties to your `<a>`

To have them next to each other, you could 2 things: (*notice that i fix some CSS issues in your code*)

**Float:**

```
<p class="clearfix">
  <a href="#" class="reply">foo</a>
  <a href="#" class="reply">bar</a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both; 
  visibility: hidden;
}

a.reply {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #555;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
}

a.reply:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**Display inline-block**

```
<p>
  <a href="#" class="reply">foo</a>
  <a href="#" class="reply">bar</a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
a.reply {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

a.reply:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in your HTML, make sure it looks something like this:

```
<a class="reply">yes</a>
<a class="reply">yes</a>
```

Seems to work fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/a6EQk/1/

Also,  `<a>` elements usually need to be set to display: `block` or `inline-block` to have any dimensions.
By default `<a>` elements are set to `display:inline;`.
You might want to check out this explanation: [display:inline vs display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099030/displayinline-vs-displayblock)

Also, I see no reference to a `float` in your css. If you do use a float make sure you clear them properly.

Comment: <a> needs at least a href attribute to work (be recognised) in FireFox for example

Comment: @Mark, it should still work. Without the href it becomes a placeholder hyperlink. http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#placeholder-hyperlink

Comment: check your fiddle in FireFox please, you will see that the "links" are not behaving as such, meaning no pointer on the mouse.

Comment: @Mark, they do the same thing in other browsers, it's not just Firefox. I just left out the `href`'s. Thanks though.