# How to keep my include from making my page longer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I have a limited amount of work with js and php so this might be an easy fix:

I have a resume page and I'm using js to replace a target div on my resume as needed. This is working fine and I've placed the additional divs in a hidden div at the bottom of the page. Instead of coding the included content into the page I was calling it in via a set of php includes. I assumed as they were inside a visibility hidden div they shouldn't impact the page. While they are not visible they do make the page longer by the same height as the 3 includes combined.

Is there an easy fix to this or is it better to hard code the divs into the page itself?

(PLESE NOTE: I am having a problem adding the code clip but I can provide a link to the site if desired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually is looking for is `display: none;` property, rather than `visibility: hidden;`. The difference is, `visibility: hidden;` still occupy the same space it would with the content displayed, while `display: none;` removes the div altogether.

Also, note that `display` is not only used to show or hide an element, it also set the inline/block behaviour of an element among others, but generally: as long as it's a div, you should most likely switch between `display: none;` and `display: block;`. If it's an `<a>`, `<b>`, `<span>` or some other inline element, go with `display: inline;` instead of block. You could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099030/displayinline-vs-displayblock).

Also, the `display` property is easily configurable with jQuery with the `$('div').show()` and `$('div').hide()` functions.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I'm not being helpful!

Comment: thanks. I was aware of the display function but had never really used it. This worked perfectly!