# Where need to set display block and where not

Tags: css

My question is where i need to set display:block; to a element? I use in header section and footer but my question i have some box inside images and text there need set display block

> header,section,footer{display:block;}

Set it for ul class elements? Where is posible no set display block

> .box{display:block;}

Comment: possible duplicate of [display:inline vs display:block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099030/displayinline-vs-displayblock)

Comment: set it where you want block-level elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is brief detail about Inline & Block Elements....

**Inline elements:**

1. respect left & right margins and padding, but **not** top & bottom
2. **cannot** have a width and height set
3. allow other elements to sit to their left and right.

**Block elements:**

1. respect all of those
2. force a line break after the block element

**Inline-block elements:**

1. allow other elements to sit to their left and right
2. respect top & bottom margins and padding
3. respect height and width

**Examples of Block Elements:**

```
<p>, <div>, <form>, <header>, <nav>, <ul>, <li>, and <h1>.
```

[image]

**Examples of Inline Elements:**

```
<a>, <span>, <b>, <em>, <i>, <cite>, <mark>, and <code>.
```

[image]

[see the good article on `display block and inline elements`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Answer (score 0):

some html elements are block by nature (div, for example). Others are inline (as a, span, ...).

You must use "display:block" only if you need to render an inline element as a block.