# Display a jQuery variable inside html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having difficulty in place my jquery variable inside my html tag. For some reason the variable is being displayed outside of my div.

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            var sec = 30
            var timer = setInterval(function() { 
                $('#hideMsg span').html(sec--);
                if (sec == -1) {
                    $('#hideMsg').fadeOut('fast');
                    clearInterval(timer);
                } 
            }, 1000);
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            var randomnumber = '<div id="hideMsg"><span>30</span></div>';
            $('#warning_show').html('<div id="message_box2"><h23>Warning!</h23><p>Your account has been Inactive for some time. You will be logged out in  ' + randomnumber + ' seconds.</p><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);">&#10006;</div></div>');
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>

<div id="warning_show"></div>
```

This produces the following result:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                                         |
|   Time runs out in                      |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
30 
seconds
```

What I want to have is:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                                         |
|   Time runs out in 30 seconds           |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I've amended the title for you as this has nothing to do with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `span` isntead

```
var randomnumber = '<span id="hideMsg"><span>30</span></span>';
```

And then

```
$('#hideMsg span').html(sec--);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use span only or use div with display:inline; .

```
   var randomnumber = '<span id="hideMsg">30</span>';
```

[Fiddle](http://**Working%20fiddle%20-%3E%20http://jsfiddle.net/fby4odey/1/**)

Reason : div is block type of element ,and span is inline which displays the content inline.

[For difference ,check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099030/displayinline-vs-displayblock)

Answer (score 0):

Since div is by default display block, it goes to next line.

Try using span instead of div:

```
var randomnumber = '<span id="hideMsg"><span>30</span></span>';
```

Or use css to change its display to inline:

```
#hideMsg{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the element you're appending the seconds to should be inline. However, you can massively improve the logic here to remove the unnecessary nested `setInterval` calls. Try this:

```
<div id="warning_show">
    <div id="message_box2">
        <h23>Warning!</h23>
        <p>Your account has been Inactive for some time. You will be logged out in <span class="timeout-seconds"></span> seconds.</p>
        <div class="boxclose" id="boxclose">&#10006;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var sec = 3
$('.timeout-seconds').text(sec);

$('#boxclose').click(function() {
    $('#warning_show').hide();
    clearInterval(timer);
});

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $('.timeout-seconds').text(sec--);
    if (sec == -1) {
        $('#warning_show').fadeOut('fast');
        clearInterval(timer);
        // redirect to login screen...
    }
}, 1000);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvkjkp7g/)

If you require, you can create the HTML structure via jQuery.