# Display affecting border position

Tags: html, css, border, display, text-align

[image: The p element starts from the left end and the text is aligned inside it]

[image: The p element is in the center and the text is aligned inside it]

When the width is not hard-coded, both displays:block and inline-block place the **p element in the center** and the text is aligned inside it.(Ofcourse, in case of block the box takes up the full width and in case of inline-block the box takes up only as much width as is necessary). But when the width is hard-coded(500px in this case), both the displays are giving different results as can be seen in the two images. I am confused as to why this is happening.(The h2 element(Sample) remains in the same place throughout) Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the "display: inline-block;" statement is lining up your paragraph with the h2 heading, where as the "display: block;" is not doing so and rather keeping it default to the left of the page.

If you would like to know a little more have a look at this Stack Overflow page: [Is there any guide on "When to use display:block when :inline and when :inline-block" and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043021/is-there-any-guide-on-when-to-use-displayblock-when-inline-and-when-inline-b)

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: But display:block without a hard-coded width(say, we don't specify any width) is centered and not  kept to the left of the page. I would like to know if there is some property that is making it behave that way

Comment: Yes because it is inside of the div, so it is inheriting the div "text-align center;"  property. Move it outside of the div and it will move to the left. Or try "float: left;" while it is in the div.

Answer (score -1):

That's very simple.

`display: block`: cannot be affected by `text-align` or `vertical-align` cause he is a block !

`display: inline-block`: have the same property like `inline`, he can be affected by `text-align` or `vertical-align`.

Comment: But text-align DOES affect block elements when the width is not hard-coded. For example, the heading(Sample) is a block element but it is affected by text-align.(It is put in the center)